# In an XSD, can I provide a type name for a directly declared element

Tags: xml, xsd

In an XSD there are several complex types that are declared directly.  In the system that will use this XSD, and the resulting XML, it's just numbering these complex types:COMPLEXTYPE1, COMPLEXTYPE2...  If I add a new complex type "in the middle" this other system will renumber the types and cause errors as the numbers "move down".

I'm trying to add a TYPE name to the XSD but that doesn't work, I see this error:
*The type attribute cannot be present with either simpleType of complexType*

```
<xs:element name ="Test" type ="testType"> <!--Doesn't like type in a direct element-->
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name ="String1" type ="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name ="String2" type ="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

My initial thoughts against external declarations: Why bother for those that are just used once.  I do have types declared for common things. If later I need something more than once I'll refactor.

Reading about XSD definitions (salami slice, Russian nesting doll and venetian blind), It's looking like I will have to declare these types outside of the main schema and then pull them in.

Is there a way to add a type name to a directly declared element?  Or do I just need to declare all my types and get over it?

One last thought, maybe it's a problem with the consuming system, how do other systems handle un-named types?  Regardless, I don't have any control on the consuming system.

Comment: After reading the answers below, other research and working more on the XSD, I'm at the conclusion that what I'm asking is not possible.  I'm refactoring my XSD to pull out the anonymous types, give them type names and then using those types in the main declarations.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring a element and not a type. If you specify the type attribute on the element, you make the element of the specified type. So it is obvious that an element which has already a type (you specified) cannot have a type specified with <xs:complexType>.

If you want to declare types and extend them do this that way (a boolean):

```
<xs:simpleType name="boolean">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>A boolean value can have the values [$true, true, $false, false] indicating true or false</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:enumeration value="true"/>
<xs:enumeration value="$true"/>
<xs:enumeration value="false"/>
<xs:enumeration value="$false"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

then you can use it like

```
<xs:element name ="Test" type ="boolean">
```

Comment: Thomas, I understand what you're saying here, there are types in my XSD that I have declared like you're showing.  What I'm looking for is a way to give a directly declared element a type in the XSD for single use elements.  That will give the consuming system a type to use with the XSD / XML.  If this isn't possible then I'll have to split out those elements I have into separate type declarations.

Comment: You like to declare a single use element and its type at once?  Afaik that's not possible. You have to make global type declarations and use them in your elements.

Answer (score 0):

A `name` attribute is not used for anonymous, embedded `xs:complexType` definitions.

**If you want to name a complex type, declare it globally:**

```
<xs:complexType name="testType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="String1" type ="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="String2" type ="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

**And then you'll be able to reference the type by name:**

```
<xs:element name="Test" type="testType"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite confusing, but the general rule is that you either declare types at the top level (globally) and give them a name by which an element declaration can refer to them in a `type` attribute, or you include them inline within an element declaration and make them anonymous, in which case the type has no name and the containing element has no @type attribute.